# How can I loop through an array in Php and get 3 items at a time?

Tags: php, algorithm

I want to loop through an array in Php and get 3 items at a time, for example if an array contains these numbers: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]`
then I want to be able to loop through it and get 3 at a time, but if the list does not break evenly into 3's then get whatever is left over.

So, in this example I would want (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9), (10, 11). What is the easiest way to do this? This is what I have so far which is getting just one item at a time from the array:

```
            for ($w = 0; $w < count($decoded_photos); $w++) {
                $photo_reference = $decoded_photos[$w]["photo_reference"];
                echo "photo reference " . $photo_reference;    
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you're looking for is exactly what the `array_chunk` method does.

Have a look here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

In your case:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10, 11];
$chunked_array = array_chunk($array, 3);
print_r($chunked_array);
```

Will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 6
        )
   ...
)
```

Once you have the chunked array you can just loop over that and then output all 3 keys at a time:

```
foreach ($chunked_array as $key => $value) {
   echo $value[0];
   echo $value[1];
   echo $value[2];
}
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate -- as all basic question are after millions of questions and over 10 years of answers.